# Encapsulation in object oriented PHP - when is it really needed?

Tags: php, oop, encapsulation

I know this is kind of a question of faith and has been asked many times before, but the answers I've found were either too general, didn't apply to my use case, or didn't satisfy otherwise.

I'm currently building an application that uses classes as representation for database tables. These classes don't offer any methods of their own, I've written a parser class for each one that works with their objects and returns the data in the format I need, which makes the parent classes nothing more than data storages and makes a nice distinction between data and logic.

Now, the consensus in OOP seems to be that you always have to use getters and setters instead of accessing class attributes directly.

An argument I've often heard is that using getters and setters gives the possibility of extending those functions later on, but in my opinion this goes against YAGNI and some other concepts I can't remember the name of right now - that a method should do exactly what you would expect from its name. If I wanted to do something more than simply set a value, I would write a new method, not put that into my setter method, since that one is, per definition, only supposed to set attributes. So I might as well skip the setter and just access the attribute directly.

Another one is that you can put validation in your setters, which I already do in my API that accesses these classes. In my opinion you shouldn't just pass values and have the object tell you if your value is okay or not, but instead validate those values first before you pass them to the object.

I do understand the purpose of private/protected attributes in "usual" classes, but when the class is literally just a data container without any methods, is this really needed? In other words: is there a glaring disadvantage to using public values, when the setter methods for those (were they private) would all just look like `public function getAttr($attr) { $this->atrr = $attr; }` anyway?

Comment: Are you the only person maintaining the code? Is someone else likely to set an attribute that's expected to be a `DateTime` object (for instance) to being a date string - or something similar? Ultimately though - this question is probably going to be closed as "Primarily Opinion Based" as the only possible accurate answer is *"it depends..."*

Comment: *"Encapsulation in object oriented - when is it really needed?"* -- the [encapsulation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Encapsulation_(computer_programming)) is one of the fundamental properties of object oriented code. Without encapsulation there is no OOP but procedural programming. When object properties have setters and getters it is procedural code disguised as OOP.

Comment: "but when the class is literally just a data container without any methods"
so why it's still php classes?

Comment: @bxN5 because I'm using an ORM that requires the database tables to have corresponding classes.

Comment: A class is a combination of properties and behaviors. Since your class has no behaviors, just properties, you end up with procedural code wrapped in a class, moving towards [anemic domain model](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Anemic_domain_model).

Answer (score 1):

You only need a data structure, but the only suitable PHP construct is the class.

Typically, in object-oriented analysis, design and programming, a class is a model of a thing or concept and it encapsulates any knowledge and/or behaviour of the thing or concept.

However, in the context of this question, encapsulation is not needed since you only require a data structure.